# Excel VBA: Ink Picture Events Fail to Fire

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA script to allow an Excel sheet to scroll down a few rows normally before freezing panes at a certain point. Here is the code I would like to run whenever the user scrolls the page:

```
Sub FreezeView()
    Dim lngTopRow As Long
    With ActiveWindow.VisibleRange
        lngTopRow = .Row
    End With
    If ((lngTopRow >= 7) And (ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False)) Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("B10").Select
        ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Else
        If ((lngTopRow = 10) And (ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True)) Then
            ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = False
        End If
    End If
'    MsgBox (lngTopRow)
End Sub
```

To my knowledge, Excel VBA doesn't have any direct events to detect scrolling; however, based on [This Article](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/287154-worksheet-onscroll-event-how-cool.html), this is supposedly possible through the use of an InkPicture object. Unfortunately, the example sheet on this page is no longer hosted. I have attempted to access the InkPicture's _Painting event (and other events) to make this work, but haven't been able to get any of these events to "fire." Here is the code I have been using to try to accomplish this:

First, I have created a class module with the name "**clsInkPicEvents**" with the following code:

```
Public WithEvents InkPicEvents As InkPicture

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    MsgBox ("Initialized")
End Sub

Private Sub InkPicEvents_Click()
    MsgBox ("Click")
End Sub

Private Sub InkPicEvents_Painted(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Rect As MSINKAUTLib.IInkRectangle)
    MsgBox ("Painted")
End Sub

Private Sub InkPicEvents_Painting(ByVal hDC As Long, ByVal Rect As MSINKAUTLib.IInkRectangle, Allow As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("Painting")
End Sub

Private Sub InkPicEvents_Resize(Left As Long, Top As Long, Right As Long, Bottom As Long)
    MsgBox ("Resize")
End Sub

Private Sub InkPicEvents_Stroke(ByVal Cursor As MSINKAUTLib.IInkCursor, ByVal Stroke As MSINKAUTLib.IInkStrokeDisp, Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox ("Stroke")
End Sub
```

Then, in "**Module 1**" I have the following script to create the InkPicture object and instantiate the class. I'm really not too familiar with this so I'm not certain I am doing this correctly:

```
Private Sub AddInkPic()
    Set oInkPic1 = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add _
    (ClassType:="msinkaut.InkPicture.1", Left:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V12").Left, Top:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("V12").Top, _
    Width:=100, Height:=100)
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize1()
    Dim clsInkPic1 As clsInkPicEvents
    Set clsInkPic1 = New clsInkPicEvents
    Set clsInkPic1.InkPicEvents = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object
    clsInkPic1.InkPicEvents.SetEventInterest ICEI_Painting, True
    MsgBox (clsInkPic1.InkPicEvents.GetEventInterest(ICEI_Painting))
End Sub
```

I attempted to manually set the event interest to true for the _Painting event as I was suspicious that it was set to false by default, but that doesn't seem to have worked. I was also suspicious that one of the properties of the InkPicture object may be the cause, so attempted to change different properties such as:

```
Private Sub EditVals()
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object.Enabled = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object.InkEnabled = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object.AutoRedraw = True
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object.CollectionMode = 2
    Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects("InkPicture1").Object.EditingMode = 0
End Sub
```

But that didn't seem to change anything. Now I'm wondering if it has something to do with the Design Mode, because I notice that I can't ink the InkPicture object after it is created until I click Design Mode on and off again, so I'm wondering if the object isn't "active" until I do that, and if enabling and then disabling Design Mode might somehow "clear" the class instance or something? Really not sure. Anyway, any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'm also using an InkPicture cotrol to detect changes in the active window's zoom level. My control is not manually created through code though, so I can't offer any advice on that. It worked great (I used its `SizeChanged` and, recently, `Click` events in my case, no painting, etc.), until I noticed that after switching from one sheet to another (I have 2 sheets in my workbook), when returning to the sheet with the ink picture control on it, the cursor became the same as if I was hovering on a regular cell. Needless to say, the code in its events became useless because they were not firing...